# How do I extract texts only without html markup?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to extract the `texts` without `html` markup by using `innerText`.

```
//table is a html table structure 
var cells = table.innerText.trim()
```

The `cells` data is like the following:

```
1st cell   


  2nd cell


  3rd cell


  4th cell


  last cell
```

How do I make every cell data into `array`?

I have tried

```
cells = cells.split(' ');
```

but it doesn't work.

Any help here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `cells.replace('\n', '').replace('\r','').split(' ');` might work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just extract the text from each cell:

```
var arr=[],
    rowCells,
    myRows=table.rows;
for (var i=0; i<myRows.length; i++) {
    rowCells=myRows[i].cells;
    for (var j=0; j<rowCells.length; j++) {
        arr.push(rowCells[j].innerText.trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: `arr.push(d.innerText || d.textContent);`

Comment: @Dementic I am just following the OP who wants to use innerText. btw I prefer (d.textContent||d.innerText) because of Chrome.

Comment: you're welcome! Note that not every browser supports innerText (cf. above comments).